# react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseResources

Tags: android, tabs, react-native

I am attempting to install the sample app here: https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-scrollable-tab-view

After install, I attempt to run, but the error appears:

```
:react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.E
xecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\KJA\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-too
ls\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 23.638 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html
```

How can this be alleviated?

Comment: As suggested in the error message, you should try to run it with `--stacktrace` or `--debug` to get more precise information about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

ref: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/102

- I spent a whole lot of time trying to figure out this error, and (at least for me) it turns out to be something really stupid, and largely unrelated to the react-native-vector-icon library.
- After many hours of A-B-A testing, I have come to the conclusion that this library has some very long path names in it.
- This really adversely affects Windows users.
- If I have my project located at: `C:\Users\MyName789\Dropbox\123 Software Development -- React Native\IconExplorer` we get a total fail.
- If I move the project to: `C:\IconExplorer` everything works well.

Recommendation for Windows users: There are many files affected while running react-native run-android. Long file name addresses will result in numerous errors, including `Execution failed for task ':react-native-vector-icons:processReleaseResources'` With that said, keep your file path names as short as possible!

Comment: Any solution for Mac users with same issue?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows one could fire up regedit, then search for

```
LongPathsEnabled
```

and set it to 1.

Do a reboot afterwards and if the problem lies only within long path names, it should be gone.